# How do I use Regex to remove "Sensor_" from a data set? this is example set, ["Sensor_01", "Sensor_10"}

Tags: python, blender-2.61

How do  I use Regex to remove "Sensor_" from a data set?  this is example set, ["Sensor_01", "Sensor_10"}

??

I am having some trouble with understanding all the symbols, (dyslexia)

Comment: You are going to have to match the start of the `Sensor` word to the end of the digits after the  `_`  character. I'm sure there's better ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this:

```
dataset = ['Sensor_01', 'Sensor_02', 'Sensor_03']
for i in range(len(dataset)):
    dataset[i] = dataset[i].replace('Sensor_', '')
print dataset
```

Comment: You are most welcome. You should accept answers the solve your problems to keep your accept ratio up.

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex here, simply replace all instances of "Sensor_" with nothing. [This should help.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)

Comment: No, it needs to grab only relevant materials with the name Sensor_ otherwise it breaks the whole script,